# Is the question "Where does she hurt?" correct?

Tags: phrase-request

How can I ask someone what part of their body is in pain?
I already know that "Where does it hurt?" is common among native speakers. However, if we ask someone about a mutual friend's health (pain in part of body), how to ask?

Answer (score 2):

"Where does she hurt?" is exactly correct. You can also use "Where is she hurting?" which might be a bit more common.

You will also see "Where is she hurt?" but in this case "hurt" has the different meaning of "injured." So if you asked this, you would be asking what part of the body is injured rather than what part of the body is feeling pain.